# How to stop recording with tinycap in android?

Tags: android, tinyalsa

We're using tinycap to do some script automatically in our android phone device.

But how to give argument to stop it?

Like `tinycap -d 5 test.wav(5s)`

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you start recording? I don't know what tinymix config I should use. Every time I call tinycap /storage/emulated/0/out.wav I get start errorCaptured 0 frames message.

Answer (score 0):

Depends which version you're using. On 22 Jan 2016, virajkarandikar has submitted this [patch](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/commit/8eaad66708839555a852b2c268e9d90208865470), which introduces a timeout switch, e.g for 5 seconds:

```
tinycap test.wav -t 5
```

Lazy workaround if not implemented and can't rebuild:

```
tinycap test.wav &
sleep 5
pkill -TERM tinycap
```

Comment: Thank you random_clyde.
I have solved like before: pID="$(pgrep tinycap)";kill -2 $pID

Answer (score 0):

timeout 5s tinycap -d 5 test.wav